# Confused by shell pipe command

Tags: shell, pipe

So I'm doing a program in C that emulates a pipe command in the shell but I'm confused by it. I know that it searches something in my directory, sorts it and ads it to a file.txt, but I don't know what it searches.

```
find . -type f -ls | cut -c 2- | sort -n -k 7 >file.txt ; less <file.txt
```

Can someone tell me what it does?

Comment: `man find` would reveal that it searches for...regular files.

Comment: search for regular file and suppress first two caracters (?) befor sort it and write output to file.txt. Maybe your version of find does not work as mine (to explain cut command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -ls | cut -c 2- | sort -n -k 7 >file.txt ; less <file.txt
```

That's a very strange command.  Are you sure you've copied it correctly? Where did it come from?

I suggest breaking down the command, piping the output of partial versions through `less`, so you can see what's going on. (And of course you should read all the relevant man pages if you haven't already.)

```
find . | less
find . -type f | less
find . -type f -ls | less
find . -type f -ls | cut -c 2- | less
...
```

Or use `head` rather than `less` so you can see the first few lines of the output.

`find . -type f` recursively finds all ordinary files under the current directory (`'.'`). The `-ls` option tells it to show one line for each file, in a format similar to that produced by `ls -l`.

The output of `find ... -ls` starts with the numeric inode number. That number might be printed with leading spaces.

`cut -c 2-` deletes the first two characters of the each line of the output of `less`. I don't know why you'd want to do that. I suspect the idea is to ensure that there are no spaces at the beginning of the line, but it's not a reliable way to do that. If the inode number happens to be small enough, there could be three or more leading spaces. This would be better done as `sed 's/^ *//'` -- but it's not even necessary.

`sort -n -k 7` sorts numerically on the 7th blank-delimited field, which happens to be the size in bytes of the file. So this is sorting the listing by the size of the files, from smallest to largest. The previous `cut` command was, I guess, intended to ensure that the size would be the 7th field even if the original line started with blanks, but that's not necessary (unless perhaps it's for a version of `sort` that behaves a bit differently).

The output is written to `file.txt`, which is then viewed using `less <file.txt`. The `<` is silly; `less` is perfectly capable of reading from a file named on its command line, so `less file.txt` would work. Apparently the user wanted to save the output; otherwise it would have made more sense to pipe the output of `sort` to `less`. The `tee` command could also have been useful here: `find ... | tee file.txt | less`.

The output of `find ... -ls`, like the output of `ls -l`, is meant to be human-readable; it's *not* intended for automatic text processing. It might vary slightly from one implementation to another. There are ways to produce more regular output. If you have GNU `find`, it has a `-printf` option that lets you specify *exactly* what information it prints, and in what order.

Comment: I copied from the exercise my teacher gave. Wow thank you so much for this info. It will help alot

Answer (score 1):

`find . -type f` searches for regular files in the current directory (`.` means current directory) or any subdirectories and `-ls` just print the result in the same format as `ls`. `cut -c 2-` removes the 2 first chars from the output of `find`, then it gets sorted numerically and typed into a file which is then read with `less`. *phew*

Answer (score 0):

1. Man find
2. Man cut
3. Man sort
4. Man less